# useEffect validation in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

So i'm fairly new to react and im trying to make a pinpad screen now but im stuck.
i dont know how to use useEfect for validation of a 4 digits pin in my app,
as in, i am just confused where and how to write it so it actually works, is there any examples of it so i can see how to do it?

```
    export default function App() {
  const [pin, setPin] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{pin}</div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}1`)}>1</button>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}2`)}>2</button>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}3`)}>3</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}4`)}>4</button>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}5`)}>5</button>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}6`)}>6</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}7`)}>7</button>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}8`)}>8</button>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}9`)}>9</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => pin.slice(0, pin.length - 1))}>
            &lt;
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => setPin((pin) => `${pin}0`)}>0</button>
          <button onClick={() => setPin("")}>C</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for changes in your `pin` state using the `useEffect` dependency array, and then log the saved PIN if it reaches four digits.

In this example I've used an array to store the numbers which I then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) up. (I've also taken the liberty of using CSS Grid, and a Button component, so that code is as DRY as possible).

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example({ test }) {

  const [ pin, setPin ] = useState('');
  const [ attempt, setAttempt ] = useState(0);
  const [ lock, setLock ] = useState(false);
  const [ message, setMessage ] = useState('');

  // Reset the state if the "number" is "C"
  // otherwise add the number to the state string
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { number } = e.target.dataset;
    if (number === 'C') {
      setPin([]);
    } else {
      setPin(`${pin}${number}`);
    }
  }

  // If the pin state has changed,
  // and the length of the array is four,
  // log the state
  useEffect(() => {
    if (attempt < 3) {
      if (pin.length === 4) {
        if (pin !== test) {
          setAttempt(attempt + 1);
          setPin('');
          setMessage('Incorrect PIN.');
          setTimeout(() => setMessage(''), 2000);

        } else {
          setMessage('PIN accepted');
        }
      }
    } else {
      setMessage('Failed to log in.');
      setLock(true);
      setTimeout(() => setLock(false), 3000);
    }
  }, [pin]);

  function maskedPin() {
    let str = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < pin.length; i++) {
      str += '*';
    }
    return str;
  }

  // Create a new array and map over the elements
  // to create some buttons
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="grid">
        {new Array(9).fill('').map((el, i) => (
          <Button lock={lock} number={i + 1} handleClick={handleClick} />
        ))}
        <Button lock={lock} number="0" handleClick={handleClick} />
        <Button lock={lock} number="C" handleClick={handleClick} />
      </div>
      <div class="pin">{maskedPin()}</div>
      <div class="message">{message}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Button({ lock, number, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <button
      disabled={lock}
      data-number={number}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >{number}</button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example test="1234" />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.grid { width: 100px; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); gap: 10px; }
.message { margin-top: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: TYSM for this great example! also what do i do if i want it to only have 3 tries? like does it need an Else in my if statement?

Comment: So you have a PIN you're checking against, like 1234, and if it's correct do something but if it's failed after 3 times do something else?

Comment: yes, i want to validate a 1234 pin for example, in which you only have 3 tries, else the keys get locked.

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer. `test` is passed into the component as a prop and we use that to test the PIN. PIN is now a string rather than an array as it's a little easier to manage.

Comment: I also added a new state called "lock" which the buttons use to determine if they should be disabled after the 3rd attempt.

Comment: thank you a lot, sorry i keep asking questions, but one more, if i want to update a "message" on a screen, sayin "okay" when pin is correct, or "error" when its not, should i update it again, with useState?

Comment: Using state might be easier. Just have a message state, and update that if the PIN does/doesn't work, or if the number of tries > 3. Answer updated. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your time and help, i understood everything perfectly.

Comment: Hooray! Glad I did something useful today :) Good luck with the coding!

Comment: YES, thanks a lot, also! i have been trying to set TimeOut for my lock(so it unlocks after 30 secs) but it doesnt work because im quite unsure of it, where should i add the timeout?

Comment: You can add a setTimeout like I've done in my updated answer :) Just adjust the 3000 to 30000.

Comment: thanks a lot, i learned sm from you! also is there a way i can change the digits to * after entering or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `useEffect` hook with `pin` as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(pin, pin.length)
}, [pin])
```

the callback passed to `useEffect` will be called every time `pin` changes

Answer (score 1):

To validate any react state when state change you can use `useEffect` like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
   // pin state changed
}, [pin]);
```

`useEffect` can be used when component mount, unmount or any state variable changes. Variables which are used inside square brackets (`pin` in this example) are called dependent variables. That means when this variables changes it will run that specific code.

For more [React useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)